# Android Retrofit POST ArrayList

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking

Trying to send `List<String>` to server and have Bad Request Error.

```
public interface PostReviewApi {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/")
        void addReview(@Field("review[place_id]") int placeId, @Field("review[content]") String review,
                       @Field("review[rating]") float rating, @Field("review[tag_list]") List<String> tagsList, Callback<ReviewEntity> callback);
    }

...
    postApi.addReview(mRestaurantId, reviewText, (float) mRating, tagsList, new Callback<ReviewEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void success(ReviewEntity reviewEntity, Response response) {
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Make `@Field("review[tag_list[]]")` doesn't help either

Comment: @Field will be reflected as name of the field, making it look like an array does not really make the value array.!

Comment: @Ramesh, thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `@Body` annotation instead of `@Field` and passing a single `ReviewBody` object.

```
class ReviewBody {

    public Review review;

    public ReviewBody(int placeId, float rating, String content, List<String> tagList) {
        review = new Review(placeId, rating, content, tagList);
    }

    public class Review {
        @SerializedName("place_id")
        public int placeId;
        public float rating; 
        public String content;
        @SerializedName("tag_list")
        public List<String> tagList;

        public Review(int placeId, float rating, String content, List<String> tagList) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.rating = rating;
            this.content = content;
            this.tagList = tagList;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@POST("/")
void addReview(@Body ReviewBody body, Callback<ReviewEntity> callback);
```

(without `@FormUrlEncoded`)

Answer (score 1):

**@Field annotations** is used for form-encoded request. Egs,

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/")
 Call<ResponseBody> example(
     @Field("name") String name,
     @Field("occupation") String occupation);


Calling with foo.example("Bob Smith", "President") yields a request body of name=Bob+Smith&occupation=President.
```

However you wont be able to send ArrayList tagList using @Field annotation.

Instead create a Config class and annotate the class variables as **@SerializedName ("XYZ")** followed by variable name to enable **serialization of Array List** in Retrofit. Please find the below code for reference,

```
  public class Hotels {

  private @SerializedName("place_id") int mRestaurantId;
  private @SerializedName("content") String review;
  private @SerializedName("rating") float rating;
  private @SerializedName("tag_list") List<String> tagsList;

  public int getmRestaurantId() {
    return mRestaurantId;
  }

  public void setmRestaurantId(int mRestaurantId) {
    this.mRestaurantId = mRestaurantId;
  }

  public String getReview() {
    return review;
  }

  public void setReview(String review) {
    this.review = review;
  }

  public float getRating() {
    return rating;
  }

  public void setRating(float rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
  }

  public List<String> getTagsList() {
    return tagsList;
  }

  public void setTagsList(List<String> tagsList) {
    this.tagsList = tagsList;
  }
```

Further you can **define your interface** as follows,

```
@POST("/") Call<ReviewEntity> addReview(@Body Hotels hotels);
```

Hope this might help in future prospects

Comment: how to use it within multipart to upload an image besides the use of List?... and thanks your answer helped me.

Comment: hey @Mahmoud you cannot add "Body" parameter with "@Multipart" annotation in retrofit. But you can add your fields as path parameters in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `Multipart`:

```
@Part("item_ids[]") items : List<Int>
```

Full Example:

Assuming in registeration you want to (send user data - upload image and list of any)

```
@Multipart
@POST(REGISTER_LINK)
suspend fun register(
    @PartMap partMap: MutableMap<String, RequestBody>, // (name, email..etc)
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part?, // image file
    @Part("item_ids[]") listOf: List<Int> // list of
): NetworkResponse<>
```