# Retrofit sending Multipart and Form data in single request

Tags: android, image, retrofit, multipartform-data

In my application i need to send an image and array of phone numbers and some unique values to server using retrofit. Here is the code that i have been used, the following code is working if i have removed image from request.

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/groups")
    @Headers("Accept:application/json")
    void createGroupRequest(@Header("mobile-number") String mPhone, @Header("uid") String imei,@Field("group[identification_name]") String jid, @Field("group[name]") String mName,@Field("group[mobile_numbers][]") String[] mMemberNos, Callback<RetrofitResponse> response);
```

Now i need to send an image data in this request, but how it possible to use both FormUrlEncoded and a multipart data in same request...? is there any other approach in Retrofit..?

Comment: have you added the @Multipart annotation

Comment: @PramodYadav , yes i had tried that but got error that only Multipart or FormUrlEncoded can be used both are not allowded. if i have used Multipart then how can i convert these working FormUrlEncoded data to Multipart..?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224358/1993204)

Comment: @blipinsk i had checked the above link you have given, but how can i add image file along with this request..?

Comment: Any update on this issue..??

Answer (score 1):

Please check my code hope it will help you

```
    private RestAdapter     adapter;
    private ApiListener     apis;

    adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(BASE_URL).build();
    apis = adapter.create(ApiListener.class);

TypedString userName = new TypedString("userName");
TypedString name = new TypedString("name");
TypedString emailAddress = new TypedString("emailAddress");
TypedString password = new TypedString("password");

File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separator+"Koala.jpg");
TypedFile photoTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", photoFile);
apis.registerUser(userName,name,emailAddress,password,photoTypedFile, new Callback<BaseResponseVo>()
    {
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0)
        {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void success(BaseResponseVo arg0, Response arg1)
        {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });



public interface ApiListener
{
@Multipart
@POST("/user/add")
public void registerUser(@Part("userName") TypedString username,@Part("name") TypedString name,@Part("emailAddress") TypedString email,@Part("password") TypedString password,@Part("userPhotoURL") TypedFile photo,Callback<BaseResponseVo> response);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can i include array of string phone numbers in your code..? 

And in this part,
TypedString userName = new TypedString("userName");
should i use my username variable in "userName"..? it is confusing me with Part("userName")... :)

Comment: Part("UserName") is your request object along with your file object . you need to send your file object using "TypedFile"  and rest of objects you need to send using "TypedString"

Comment: i have tried your code but you can see from my above code i need to send a string array also with this request.. please see my code 

TypedString groupId = new TypedString(mGroupJid);
TypedString identification = new TypedString(mGroupNameText);
TypedString[] array = new TypedString[50];
 int j = 0;
 for(String jid : mMembersList){
 TypedString str = new TypedString(jid);
 array[j] = str;
 j++;
Log.e("TAg","................. array "+array[j]+" str "+str+" jid "+jid);
 }

It is not woking.....