# Retrofit POST request using @Body returns empty response body

Tags: java, android, arraylist, retrofit

I am trying to send data to server with end point like this:
`https://api.test.com/sales/taken?key=1a2b3c&sales_number=abc&taken[0][id_product]=123&taken[0][qty]=123&taken[1][id_product]=123&taken[1][qty]=123`

According to [Android Retrofit POST ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224092/android-retrofit-post-arraylist), best way to send a list is by using `@Body` instead of `@Field`.
So i made a model to suit the end point like this:

```
public class Model {

    @SerializedName("key")
    private String key;

    @SerializedName("sales_number")
    private String sales_number;

    @SerializedName("taken")
    private List<Taken> taken;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getSales_number() {
        return sales_number;
    }

    public void setSales_number(String sales_number) {
        this.sales_number = sales_number;
    }

    public List<NotaAmbilDetailModel> getTaken() {
        return taken;
    }

    public void setTaken(List<NotaAmbilDetailModel> taken) {
        this.taken = taken;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Taken {

    @SerializedName("id_product")
    private int id_product;

    @SerializedName("qty")
    private int qty;

    public int getId_product() {
        return id_product;
    }

    public void setId_product(int id_product) {
        this.id_product = id_product;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

My post interface looks like this:

```
@POST("/sales/taken")
Call<ResponseModel> sendData(@Body Model model);
```

Response status is:
`Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.test.com/sales/taken}`.

As you can see, response code is 200 but when i tried to get the response body, `java.lang.NullPointerException` occurred.

My error log is:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ResponseModel.getCode()' on a null object reference
D/Response: LOG: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://api.test.com/sales/taken}
Response Body: ResponseModel@bb5e4cf
```

Comment: you have to use query param instead of body

Comment: It is depending on your server not retrofit problem.

Comment: Could you please post your stack trace

Comment: @ytRino So nothing is wrong with my model and post interface?

Comment: @PaulBrugman That is also depends on server. If the server accept json(depending on your ConverterFactory class), your request could be correct but if the server only accept GET with query parameter, your request would be wrong.

Comment: @ytRino Ah, i see. Ok, gonna consult with back-end then. Thank you.

Comment: @RajasekaranM Hello, is it something like this? @Query"key" String Key, @Query"sales_number" String sales_number, @Query"taken" List<Taken> taken; ?

Comment: yes @PaulBrugman, you are right, and you can use QueryMap if have to much of params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api request expecting query params instead of request body.

Try like this

**Request**

```
@POST("/sales/taken")
Call<ResponseModel> sendData(@QueryMap Map<String, String> queryMap);
```

**Params for api**

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
queryMap.put("key", "value_for_key");
queryMap.put("sales_number", "value_for_sales_number");
queryMap.put("taken[0][id_product]", "value_for_taken[0][id_product]");
queryMap.put("taken[0][qty]", "value_for_taken[0][qty]");
queryMap.put("taken[1][id_product]", "value_for_taken[1][id_product]");
queryMap.put("taken[1][qty]", "value_for_taken[1][qty]");
....
```

Comment: This is working for me since my server can't accept JSON at the moment. Thank you.